# 'int' object is not subscriptable error in recursion

Tags: python, function, recursion

I'm trying to make a recursive function where it takes all odd numbers in a list, order them in an ascending way, and then comes the even numbers but descending.

For example:

`lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 11, 13, 14, 15, 17, 18]` would return `[1, 3, 11, 13, 15, 17, 18, 14, 6, 4, 2]`

This is my code:

```
def REC_fun(lst):
    lst2 , lst3 = [] , []
    
    if len(lst) == 1:
        return lst[0]
    temp = REC_fun(lst[1:])
    if temp[0]%2 == 1:
        lst2 += [temp[0]]
    else:
        lst3 += [temp[0]]
    return lst2 + lst3[::-1]

ls = [1, 2, 3, 6, 11, 13, 14, 15, 17, 18]
REC_fun(ls)
```

The problem is probably with `temp`, I want to check each time if the first number of the list is even or odd and add it accordingly to the empty lists (`lst2` and `lst3`), but I don't know how.. I keep getting this error

```
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_16808/3849482424.py in REC_fun(lst)
      7     if len(lst) == 1:
      8         return lst[0]
----> 9     temp = make_pyramid(lst[1:])
     10     if temp[0]%2 == 1:
     11         lst2 += [temp[0]]

~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_16808/3849482424.py in REC_fun(lst)
      8         return lst[0]
      9     temp = make_pyramid(lst[1:])
---> 10     if temp[0]%2 == 1:
     11         lst2 += [temp[0]]
     12     else:

TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

### EDIT -

I changed the first return from `return lst[0]` to `return lst` and the output is now `[18]`.

Comment: Please [edit] your post and add the full Traceback of your `TypeError`.

Comment: You always want to return a list.  So, change the first return to `return lst`.  You know if only has one entry.

Comment: @TimRoberts I did.. now my output is `[18]`

Comment: Please read [ask] and https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/, and think carefully about the program logic. This is not a code-writing service nor a discussion forum. We require a much more specific question than this. Right now I do not see a question at all.

Comment: @ProgrammingNoob -- That's because of your algorithm.  When you get the recursive answer, you are just appending to an empty list.  Instead, you need to append the NEW value to the correct end of the `temp` list you got back and return that.

Answer (score 0):

**Here is your Answer:**

```
lst2, lst3 = [],[]
def REC_fun(lst):
 global lst2 ,lst3
 if lst[0]%2 == 1:
    lst2 += [lst[0]]
 else:
    lst3 += [lst[0]]

 if len(lst) == 1:
    return lst
 lst = REC_fun(lst[1:])

 return lst2 + lst3[::-1]
ls = [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 11, 13, 14, 15, 17, 18]
print(REC_fun(ls))
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [answer] and note well that this is not a code-writing service; please only attempt to answer questions that meet the standards for asking. When answering, make sure to **write an explanation**; don't just show code. Also, do not delete and re-post answers in order to fix the formatting. Instead, [edit] to fix posts.